# jQuery Coda Slider Last Slide is missing in IE 5,6,7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am working on a site with the current working copy held at: www.OnlineUticaCollege.com/david

I'm not all that familiar with the code slider in jQuery tools, but I know how to program so it's rather easy to make sense of.

I've searched through multiple posts on here and other sites to find a similar problem (and hopefully a solution) but to no avail.

What is happening is the last tab in the Code Slider ("Contact Us") is not showing up. I've verified that the content is there and it displays just fine in every browser except IE 5,6,7,8 that I have tried out so far.

Any help is appreciated.

[edit]
Patrick,

Sorry about not providing a code example, I blame lack of sleep :P

```
<script src="tabbed-bottom-nav/js/jquery-1.2.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="tabbed-bottom-nav/js/jquery-easing.1.2.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="tabbed-bottom-nav/js/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="tabbed-bottom-nav/js/coda-slider.1.1.1-.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript">
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).bind("load", function()jQuery("div#slider1").codaSlider()});
</script>
```

There's the includes and initialization of the slider itself.
Here's the content:

```
<div class="panel" title="CONTACT US"><!--Begin Contact Us: panel--><div class="wrapper"> <img style="margin-left: 10px;" src="[link is here]" alt="" align="right" />
<p>Your questions, comments and suggestions are important to us.
Do you have questions about a program, certification programs or start dates?</p>
<p>Please call us toll-free at <strong>(###) ###-####</strong> to speak with a knowledgeable Program Manager or <a href="[link is here]"><strong><u>fill out our online information request form.</u></strong></a></p>
</div></div><!--End Contact Us: panel-->
```

As for the Javascript error, I attempted to debug it with Firebug, but no error comes up. I'm playing a game of pin the tail on the code currently by just removing parts to find what it is that is causing the error in IE.

Thanks for your response!

Comment: It helps to have a code example that is stripped down to a bare minimum instead of an entire site to dig through. I don't have an answer, but I did get a js error when opening the site in IE7, so that may be a start. My guess is that it has something to do with the container that holds the 5 panels. If it is not wide enough, the last panel will probably 'wrap' and end up out of sight. I think that with that particular slider, the container width is calculated in js, so there may be a correlation between the js error I got and the last panel disappearing.

Comment: Any option to use jQuery 1.3? It has a *lot* of bugfixes as opposed to 1.2. Might solve your actual problem as well.

Comment: I'll give it a try and see what the result is BalusC, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. What it was that for some reason the last tab was always being pushed back. I tested it by inserting a bunch of blank content and then finally removing one tab and the last tab was still blank. What it was was that for some reason the last person who made their original site ended up putting a huge margin on the last tab...who knows why...lol

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

it happen because pictures in container a little more widely than slider items

Add attribute width="500" to image, per example